# How to set Action on Spinner OnItemSelectionListener in following code

Tags: java, android, android-spinner, onitemclicklistener

I want to use this following code in getView

```
fromSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long arg3) {

            fromSpinner.setSelection(position);
            fromSpinner.setSelected(true);
            sourceRowPosition = position;

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

        }
});
```

Comment: what do you want to do??

Comment: I have 2 spinners...one denote source language other is destination language....they have edittext associated with it containing source lang word and destination language word...We have a button too which translate word in edittext1 to other word depending upon destination language. In this way we maintain a listview of the words. I want that if I change the  destination language from spinner...it will reflect changes automatically to all list words and vice versa too

Answer (score 0):

Just use onItemClicklistener same way you use for listview, this will resolve your issue

Comment: When I am adding it to getView method of customAdapter class...it is giving Null Pointer exception

Comment: I need to perform translate button's logic on ItemClickListener

Comment: what exactly you want to do ?

Comment: see... when I click Translatebutton....its code in getView method gets executed.....button when I try to do same thing using spinner onItemSelectedListener ...Application close down giving null pointer exception